# C pointers: When you dereference a char pointer and try to store an int, will it store the whole int?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say you have:

```
    void *p = // something;
    int size = 10;
    *((char *)p + 8) = size ^ 1;
```

I know this looks like really random logic, but I was wondering if it would still do as intended. I am trying to place the entirety of "size ^ 1" at the address pointed to by "p + 8" when p is casted to a char. Basically what I am asking is, is it any different from:

```
    *((int *)p + 2) = size ^ 1;
```

Also, what would happen if I had chosen to increment the pointers by 3, for example:

```
    *((char *)p + 3) = size ^ 1;
```

or (I know this isn't equivalent to all the others, but want to see if this is right):

```
    *((int *)p + 3) = size ^ 1;
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Comment: @Steve, that's one approach, but what happens to him might not happen to me if this turns out to be undefined or implementation defined.

Comment: Hmm... thanks to both you guys. Just wondering, but what do you mean that it could lead to undefined/implementation-defined behavior?

Comment: There are certain things you can do in a C program that may be undefined, which means that your program could do anything in that case, including (but not limited to) crashing, appearing to work fine, corrupting data somewhere, baking a cake, kicking your dog, or even activating SkyNet. Implementation defined means that as long as you're on the same computer architecture you'll get the same results. Things like the sizes of various types are implementation defined, for example. Most of the time ints are 32 bits, but sometimes they're not. It depends on the hardware you're using.

Comment: One note though, I wasn't saying that what you're doing necessarily is undefined, I was just suggesting that it might be, so simply testing it out for yourself isn't necessarily going to give you a definitive answer, because the answer might change if you try it on another computer if it turns out it is. (Sorry if I've confused you :P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you derefence a `char *` pointer, you are referring to a single `char` object.  In this way, it is very similar to:

```
char c;

c = size ^ 1;
```

That is, the resulting value (in this case, 11) is converted to type `char` and then stored at the location `(char *)p + 8` (the 9th `char` object pointed to by `p`).

So yes, it is quite different from:

```
*((int *)p + 2) = size ^ 1;
```

The latter line modifies an entire `int` object, of size `sizeof(int)`, and the object modified is the 3rd `int` object pointed to by `p`.

If we imagine that you have a little-endian system with `sizeof(int) == 4`, then your four examples will modify the memory pointed to by `p` in the following ways:

1.

```
*((char *)p + 8) = size ^ 1;

| ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | 11 | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? |
```

2.

```
*((int *)p + 2) = size ^ 1;

| ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | 11 | 00 | 00 | 00 | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? |
```

3.

```
*((char *)p + 3) = size ^ 1;

| ?? | ?? | ?? | 11 | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? |
```

4.

```
*((int *)p + 3) = size ^ 1;

| ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | 11 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
```

Answer (score 1):

`*((char *)p + 8) = size ^ 1` implicitly casts `size ^ 1` to `char`, which jettisons all but the lowest-order byte; so no, it is not the same as `*((int *)p + 2) = size ^ 1`.

Comment: But I thought that the C language in general just doesn't do bounds-checking? (meaning that even if sizes don't match, it will just go ahead and store even beyond the bounds...)

Comment: @JacobHayden: This has nothing to do with bounds checking, it is to do with types.  The type of `*((char *)p + 8)` is `char`, so operations that store into this lvalue will store only a char.

Answer (score 0):

`*((char *)p + 8) = size ^ 1;` is no different than:

```
char something;
something = size ^ 1;
```

You can figure it out from there, but better just try it and find out!